# ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing - already sorted array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib for contour plots and was able to have it working multiple times until now. For some reason, I now get the "ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing", but I have already sorted my levels array using `sort()`. I have tried many things and no results except this one error. I have no ideas as to why this was working and now is not.

For reference, I have printed out the sorted array (has 4096 entries):

```
[-0.24418033 -0.20097393 -0.19743256 ...,  0.18904521  0.19392523 0.20172809]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing any code (and not being very familiar with matplotlib), it's tough to help, but one random thought... if it truly has to be increasing and not just non-decreasing, is it possible you have two equal values in there somewhere?

Comment: Hey, That's a good thought - there are values of the same magnitude, as in there's a negative value that has a matching positive value (for example there may be like -1.2 and +1.2), so I've tried sorting different ways, like by magnitude or decreasing, but so far nothing has worked yet

Also, without sorting, there really is no order to the numbers, it;s just random.

In addition, I'm getting these numbers from the output of a wavelet transform.